# Spring boot returns 400 missing constructor no stacktrace

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a post call with a

```
public Test postTest(@RequestBody Test test) {
}


public class Test {
    @JsonProperty("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    @NotNull(message = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_NULL")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_EMPTY")
    @Email(flags = Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, message = "EMAIL_INVALID")
    private String emailAddress;

    public ForgetPassword(
            @NotNull(message = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_NULL") @Size(min = 1, 
            message = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_EMPTY") @Email(flags = 
            Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, 
            message = "EMAIL_INVALID") String emailAddress) {
        super();
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

I was missing the default constructor and it kept returning bad request when I tried to make the post. If I add the default constructor it works. It does not even throw a stack trace. I am using a custom template to send back the response in. I'm overriding the BadRequestException to send back a custom message.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Is there any method which I should override to catch such exceptions. I want to be able to know why something is going wrong and to be able to see a stack strace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Global Exceptional Handler using `@ControllerAdvice`. You can place as many handlers there using `@ExcecptionHandler`. You can log errorTrace for debugging purpose.

```
package com.startwithjava.exception;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handlerGenericError(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handlerBadRequest(BadRequestException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this but it doesn't go inside this class

Comment: Have you debug the class. It should work. Make your component scan works.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a class like below to handle exceptions.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Error processing the request, please check the logs")
    public void handleException(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred", e);
    }
}
```